# Laravel Images not showing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

I have this function to store the data for the student the image it is saved correctly in the db but when I want to accesss to it it return not found I tried this link:
`http://localhost:8000/storage/images/6tsncPbIw6PmU91GclYGJWSPLqOB3WjN8JTyrRdO.png`
it was working normally but I don't know why its not now.
And I ran `php artisan storage:link`, if anyone can help me

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:students',
            'phone_number' => ['required', 'regex:/(^70|^71|^76|^78|^79|^81|^06|^03)[0-9]{6}$/'],
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => $validator->errors()->first(),
            ], 422);
        }
        
        $student = new Student; 

        $First_name = $request->input('first_name');
        $Last_name = $request->input('last_name');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $birth_date = $request->input('birth_date');
        $phone = $request->input('phone_number');
        $enroll = $request->input('enrollment_date');
        //$headshot = $request->input('headshot');
        $image_path = $request->file('image')->store('images', 'public');
        $section_id = $request->input('section_id');
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'regex:/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix'
        ]);
        $section = Section::find($section_id);

        // Check if we don't have a section
        if (!$section) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'No section found to add a new student',
            ], 404);
        }

        // Check if the section reach the max of students
        $studentCount = $section->student()->count(); 
        if ($studentCount >= $section->capacity) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'The section has reached its capacity',
            ], 400);
        }

        $student->first_name = $First_name;
        $student->last_name = $Last_name;
        $student->email = $email;
        $student->birth_date = $birth_date;
        $student->phone_number = $phone;
        $student->enrollment_date = $enroll;
        // $student->headshot = $headshot;
        $student->headshot = $image_path;
        $student->Section()->associate($section);
        $student->save();


        return  response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Student was successfully added',
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, in de public folder, can you see the storage symlink in there? If so, you can try to delete the storage symlink from the public folder. Then retry the php artisan storage:link

Comment: do you mean delete the images folder where they are saved?

Comment: I have storage/app/public/images and when I run php artisan storage:link it will return already exist

Comment: Hi, the storage:link will create a symbolic folder in your /public folder. You can safely delete this folder. Then you can run the storage:link cmd again. Make sure you delete teh storage folder in the public folder. Do not delete the storage/app/public/images folder, this will delete your images itself.

Comment: Hello, in the public folder, I just have the images folder, and when I run php artisan storage:link it will return that already exist, I should have this path storage/app/public/storage/images?

Answer (score 0):

cant comment. First of the code you shown here is of creating a new student which you afirms works correctly. Sharing the code of where you get the image will help us know how to help.

i mean where you call the `{{asset($path_to_public_folder)}}` will help us know how to help

Comment: Hello, tbh I just have this route for images I didn't call the asset and for this project, I was using it and everything was working fine, now even if I run php artisan storage:link it will return already exists, I formatted my laptop and I copy the project to the external hard and I passed it so from the first run it returned already exists.

Comment: okay i want to know where in the `config/filesystems.php` did you set the `"default" => env("FILESYSTEM_DISK", "public")` mostly is local by default. if is local change to public

Comment: Hello, I changed it and still not working